ExceptionHandlerExceptionResolver : Failure in @ExceptionHandler
I set up springboot's global exception handling.
@ControllerAdvice
class SageExceptionHandler() {
    @ExceptionHandler(value = [BadRequestException::class, HttpMessageNotReadableException::class])
    fun badRequestExceptionHandler(e: BadRequestException): ResponseEntity<Unit> {
        logger.error("badRequestExceptionHandler")
        return ResponseEntity.badRequest().build()
    }
}

But when I pass in a request parameter that doesn't match what was asked for, the global exception handling doesn't catch this exception.
2024-08-11T12:13:54.406+08:00  WARN 12924 --- [nio-8080-exec-6] .m.m.a.ExceptionHandlerExceptionResolver : Failure in @ExceptionHandler com.sage.server.exception.SageExceptionHandler#badRequestExceptionHandler(BadRequestException)


java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not resolve parameter [0] in public org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity<kotlin.Unit> com.sage.server.exception.SageExceptionHandler.badRequestExceptionHandler(com.sage.server.core.service.excption.BadRequestException): No suitable resolver
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.getMethodArgumentValues(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:221) ~[spring-web-6.1.5.jar:6.1.5]
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:178) ~[spring-web-6.1.5.jar:6.1.5]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:118) ~[spring-webmvc-6.1.5.jar:6.1.5]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ExceptionHandlerExceptionResolver.doResolveHandlerMethodException(ExceptionHandlerExceptionResolver.java:432) ~[spring-webmvc-6.1.5.jar:6.1.5]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.AbstractHandlerMethodExceptionResolver.doResolveException(AbstractHandlerMethodExceptionResolver.java:74) ~[spring-webmvc-6.1.5.jar:6.1.5]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.AbstractHandlerExceptionResolver.resolveException(AbstractHandlerExceptionResolver.java:175) ~[spring-webmvc-6.1.5.jar:6.1.5]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.HandlerExceptionResolverComposite.resolveException(HandlerExceptionResolverComposite.java:80) ~[spring-webmvc-6.1.5.jar:6.1.5]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.processHandlerException(DispatcherServlet.java:1357) ~[spring-webmvc-6.1.5.jar:6.1.5]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.processDispatchResult(DispatcherServlet.java:1160) ~[spring-webmvc-6.1.5.jar:6.1.5]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:1106) ~[spring-webmvc-6.1.5.jar:6.1.5]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:979) ~[spring-webmvc-6.1.5.jar:6.1.5]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:1014) ~[spring-webmvc-6.1.5.jar:6.1.5]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doPost(FrameworkServlet.java:914) ~[spring-webmvc-6.1.5.jar:6.1.5]
    at jakarta.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:590) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.19.jar:6.0]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:885) ~[spring-webmvc-6.1.5.jar:6.1.5]
    at jakarta.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:658) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.19.jar:6.0]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:205) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.19.jar:10.1.19]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:149) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.19.jar:10.1.19]
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:51) ~[tomcat-embed-websocket-10.1.19.jar:10.1.19]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:174) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.19.jar:10.1.19]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:149) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.19.jar:10.1.19]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.AbstractRequestLoggingFilter.doFilterInternal(AbstractRequestLoggingFilter.java:289) ~[spring-web-6.1.5.jar:6.1.5]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:116) ~[spring-web-6.1.5.jar:6.1.5]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:174) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.19.jar:10.1.19]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:149) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.19.jar:10.1.19]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.CompositeFilter$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(CompositeFilter.java:108) ~[spring-web-6.1.5.jar:6.1.5]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.lambda$doFilterInternal$3(FilterChainProxy.java:231) ~[spring-security-web-6.2.3.jar:6.2.3]
    at org.springframework.security.web.ObservationFilterChainDecorator$FilterObservation$SimpleFilterObservation.lambda$wrap$1(ObservationFilterChainDecorator.java:479) ~[spring-security-web-6.2.3.jar:6.2.3]
    at org.springframework.security.web.ObservationFilterChainDecorator$AroundFilterObservation$SimpleAroundFilterObservation.lambda$wrap$1(ObservationFilterChainDecorator.java:340) ~[spring-security-web-6.2.3.jar:6.2.3]
    at org.springframework.security.web.ObservationFilterChainDecorator.lambda$wrapSecured$0(ObservationFilterChainDecorator.java:82) ~[spring-security-web-6.2.3.jar:6.2.3]
    at org.springframework.security.web.ObservationFilterChainDecorator$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(ObservationFilterChainDecorator.java:128) ~[spring-security-web-6.2.3.jar:6.2.3]
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.AuthorizationFilter.doFilter(AuthorizationFilter.java:100) ~[spring-security-web-6.2.3.jar:6.2.3]
    at org.springframework.security.web.ObservationFilterChainDecorator$ObservationFilter.wrapFilter(ObservationFilterChainDecorator.java:240) ~[spring-security-web-6.2.3.jar:6.2.3]
    at org.springframework.security.web.ObservationFilterChainDecorator$ObservationFilter.doFilter(ObservationFilterChainDecorator.java:227) ~[spring-security-web-6.2.3.jar:6.2.3]
    at org.springframework.security.web.ObservationFilterChainDecorator$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(ObservationFilterChainDecorator.java:137) ~[spring-security-web-6.2.3.jar:6.2.3]
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter.doFilter(ExceptionTranslationFilter.java:126) ~[spring-security-web-6.2.3.jar:6.2.3]
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter.doFilter(ExceptionTranslationFilter.java:120) ~[spring-security-web-6.2.3.jar:6.2.3]
    at org.springframework.security.web.ObservationFilterChainDecorator$ObservationFilter.wrapFilter(ObservationFilterChainDecorator.java:240) ~[spring-security-web-6.2.3.jar:6.2.3]
    at org.springframework.security.web.ObservationFilterChainDecorator$ObservationFilter.doFilter(ObservationFilterChainDecorator.java:227) ~[spring-security-web-6.2.3.jar:6.2.3]
    at org.springframework.security.web.ObservationFilterChainDecorator$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(ObservationFilterChainDecorator.java:137) ~[spring-security-web-6.2.3.jar:6.2.3]
    at org.springframework.security.web.session.SessionManagementFilter.doFilter(SessionManagementFilter.java:131) ~[spring-security-web-6.2.3.jar:6.2.3]
    at org.springframework.security.web.session.SessionManagementFilter.doFilter(SessionManagementFilter.java:85) ~[spring-security-web-6.2.3.jar:6.2.3]
    at org.springframework.security.web.ObservationFilterChainDecorator$ObservationFilter.wrapFilter(ObservationFilterChainDecorator.java:240) ~[spring-security-web-6.2.3.jar:6.2.3]
    at org.springframework.security.web.ObservationFilterChainDecorator$ObservationFilter.doFilter(ObservationFilterChainDecorator.java:227) ~[spring-security-web-6.2.3.jar:6.2.3]
    at org.springframework.security.web.ObservationFilterChainDecorator$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(ObservationFilterChainDecorator.java:137) ~[spring-security-web-6.2.3.jar:6.2.3]
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.java:100) ~[spring-security-web-6.2.3.jar:6.2.3]
    at org.springframework.security.web.ObservationFilterChainDecorator$ObservationFilter.wrapFilter(ObservationFilterChainDecorator.java:240) ~[spring-security-web-6.2.3.jar:6.2.3]
    at org.springframework.security.web.ObservationFilterChainDecorator$ObservationFilter.doFilter(ObservationFilterChainDecorator.java:227) ~[spring-security-web-6.2.3.jar:6.2.3]
    at org.springframework.security.web.ObservationFilterChainDecorator$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(ObservationFilterChainDecorator.java:137) ~[spring-security-web-6.2.3.jar:6.2.3]
    at org.springframework.security.web.servletapi.SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.java:179) ~[spring-security-web-6.2.3.jar:6.2.3]
    at org.springframework.security.web.ObservationFilterChainDecorator$ObservationFilter.wrapFilter(ObservationFilterChainDecorator.java:240) ~[spring-security-web-6.2.3.jar:6.2.3]
    at org.springframework.security.web.ObservationFilterChainDecorator$ObservationFilter.doFilter(ObservationFilterChainDecorator.java:227) ~[spring-security-web-6.2.3.jar:6.2.3]
    at org.springframework.security.web.ObservationFilterChainDecorator$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(ObservationFilterChainDecorator.java:137) ~[spring-security-web-6.2.3.jar:6.2.3]
    at org.springframework.security.web.savedrequest.RequestCacheAwareFilter.doFilter(RequestCacheAwareFilter.java:63) ~[spring-security-web-6.2.3.jar:6.2.3]
    at org.springframework.security.web.ObservationFilterChainDecorator$ObservationFilter.wrapFilter(ObservationFilterChainDecorator.java:240) ~[spring-security-web-6.2.3.jar:6.2.3]
    at org.springframework.security.web.ObservationFilterChainDecorator$ObservationFilter.doFilter(ObservationFilterChainDecorator.java:227) ~[spring-security-web-6.2.3.jar:6.2.3]
    at org.springframework.security.web.ObservationFilterChainDecorator$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(ObservationFilterChainDecorator.java:137) ~[spring-security-web-6.2.3.jar:6.2.3]
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter.doFilter(LogoutFilter.java:107) ~[spring-security-web-6.2.3.jar:6.2.3]
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter.doFilter(LogoutFilter.java:93) ~[spring-security-web-6.2.3.jar:6.2.3]
    at org.springframework.security.web.ObservationFilterChainDecorator$ObservationFilter.wrapFilter(ObservationFilterChainDecorator.java:240) ~[spring-security-web-6.2.3.jar:6.2.3]
    at org.springframework.security.web.ObservationFilterChainDecorator$ObservationFilter.doFilter(ObservationFilterChainDecorator.java:227) ~[spring-security-web-6.2.3.jar:6.2.3]
    at org.springframework.security.web.ObservationFilterChainDecorator$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(ObservationFilterChainDecorator.java:137) ~[spring-security-web-6.2.3.jar:6.2.3]
    at com.sage.server.system.service.security.filter.TokenVerifyFilter.run(TokenVerifyFilter.kt:65) ~[classes/:na]
    at com.sage.server.system.service.security.filter.TokenVerifyFilter.doFilterInternal(TokenVerifyFilter.kt:34) ~[classes/:na]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:116) ~[spring-web-6.1.5.jar:6.1.5]
    at org.springframework.security.web.ObservationFilterChainDecorator$ObservationFilter.wrapFilter(ObservationFilterChainDecorator.java:240) ~[spring-security-web-6.2.3.jar:6.2.3]
    at org.springframework.security.web.ObservationFilterChainDecorator$ObservationFilter.doFilter(ObservationFilterChainDecorator.java:227) ~[spring-security-web-6.2.3.jar:6.2.3]
    at org.springframework.security.web.ObservationFilterChainDecorator$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(ObservationFilterChainDecorator.java:137) ~[spring-security-web-6.2.3.jar:6.2.3]
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.doFilter(AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.java:227) ~[spring-security-web-6.2.3.jar:6.2.3]
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.doFilter(AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.java:221) ~[spring-security-web-6.2.3.jar:6.2.3]
    at org.springframework.security.web.ObservationFilterChainDecorator$ObservationFilter.wrapFilter(ObservationFilterChainDecorator.java:240) ~[spring-security-web-6.2.3.jar:6.2.3]
    at org.springframework.security.web.ObservationFilterChainDecorator$ObservationFilter.doFilter(ObservationFilterChainDecorator.java:227) ~[spring-security-web-6.2.3.jar:6.2.3]
    at org.springframework.security.web.ObservationFilterChainDecorator$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(ObservationFilterChainDecorator.java:137) ~[spring-security-web-6.2.3.jar:6.2.3]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.CorsFilter.doFilterInternal(CorsFilter.java:91) ~[spring-web-6.1.5.jar:6.1.5]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:116) ~[spring-web-6.1.5.jar:6.1.5]
    at org.springframework.security.web.ObservationFilterChainDecorator$ObservationFilter.wrapFilter(ObservationFilterChainDecorator.java:240) ~[spring-security-web-6.2.3.jar:6.2.3]
    at org.springframework.security.web.ObservationFilterChainDecorator$ObservationFilter.doFilter(ObservationFilterChainDecorator.java:227) ~[spring-security-web-6.2.3.jar:6.2.3]
    at org.springframework.security.web.ObservationFilterChainDecorator$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(ObservationFilterChainDecorator.java:137) ~[spring-security-web-6.2.3.jar:6.2.3]
    at org.springframework.security.web.header.HeaderWriterFilter.doHeadersAfter(HeaderWriterFilter.java:90) ~[spring-security-web-6.2.3.jar:6.2.3]
    at org.springframework.security.web.header.HeaderWriterFilter.doFilterInternal(HeaderWriterFilter.java:75) ~[spring-security-web-6.2.3.jar:6.2.3]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:116) ~[spring-web-6.1.5.jar:6.1.5]
    at org.springframework.security.web.ObservationFilterChainDecorator$ObservationFilter.wrapFilter(ObservationFilterChainDecorator.java:240) ~[spring-security-web-6.2.3.jar:6.2.3]
    at org.springframework.security.web.ObservationFilterChainDecorator$ObservationFilter.doFilter(ObservationFilterChainDecorator.java:227) ~[spring-security-web-6.2.3.jar:6.2.3]
    at org.springframework.security.web.ObservationFilterChainDecorator$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(ObservationFilterChainDecorator.java:137) ~[spring-security-web-6.2.3.jar:6.2.3]
    at org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextHolderFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextHolderFilter.java:82) ~[spring-security-web-6.2.3.jar:6.2.3]
    at org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextHolderFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextHolderFilter.java:69) ~[spring-security-web-6.2.3.jar:6.2.3]
    at org.springframework.security.web.ObservationFilterChainDecorator$ObservationFilter.wrapFilter(ObservationFilterChainDecorator.java:240) ~[spring-security-web-6.2.3.jar:6.2.3]
    at org.springframework.security.web.ObservationFilterChainDecorator$ObservationFilter.doFilter(ObservationFilterChainDecorator.java:227) ~[spring-security-web-6.2.3.jar:6.2.3]
    at org.springframework.security.web.ObservationFilterChainDecorator$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(ObservationFilterChainDecorator.java:137) ~[spring-security-web-6.2.3.jar:6.2.3]
    at org.springframework.security.web.context.request.async.WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.doFilterInternal(WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.java:62) ~[spring-security-web-6.2.3.jar:6.2.3]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:116) ~[spring-web-6.1.5.jar:6.1.5]
    at org.springframework.security.web.ObservationFilterChainDecorator$ObservationFilter.wrapFilter(ObservationFilterChainDecorator.java:240) ~[spring-security-web-6.2.3.jar:6.2.3]
    at org.springframework.security.web.ObservationFilterChainDecorator$ObservationFilter.doFilter(ObservationFilterChainDecorator.java:227) ~[spring-security-web-6.2.3.jar:6.2.3]
    at org.springframework.security.web.ObservationFilterChainDecorator$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(ObservationFilterChainDecorator.java:137) ~[spring-security-web-6.2.3.jar:6.2.3]
    at org.springframework.security.web.session.DisableEncodeUrlFilter.doFilterInternal(DisableEncodeUrlFilter.java:42) ~[spring-security-web-6.2.3.jar:6.2.3]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:116) ~[spring-web-6.1.5.jar:6.1.5]
    at org.springframework.security.web.ObservationFilterChainDecorator$ObservationFilter.wrapFilter(ObservationFilterChainDecorator.java:240) ~[spring-security-web-6.2.3.jar:6.2.3]
    at org.springframework.security.web.ObservationFilterChainDecorator$AroundFilterObservation$SimpleAroundFilterObservation.lambda$wrap$0(ObservationFilterChainDecorator.java:323) ~[spring-security-web-6.2.3.jar:6.2.3]
    at org.springframework.security.web.ObservationFilterChainDecorator$ObservationFilter.doFilter(ObservationFilterChainDecorator.java:224) ~[spring-security-web-6.2.3.jar:6.2.3]
    at org.springframework.security.web.ObservationFilterChainDecorator$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(ObservationFilterChainDecorator.java:137) ~[spring-security-web-6.2.3.jar:6.2.3]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilterInternal(FilterChainProxy.java:233) ~[spring-security-web-6.2.3.jar:6.2.3]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:191) ~[spring-security-web-6.2.3.jar:6.2.3]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.CompositeFilter$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(CompositeFilter.java:113) ~[spring-web-6.1.5.jar:6.1.5]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.HandlerMappingIntrospector.lambda$createCacheFilter$3(HandlerMappingIntrospector.java:195) ~[spring-webmvc-6.1.5.jar:6.1.5]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.CompositeFilter$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(CompositeFilter.java:113) ~[spring-web-6.1.5.jar:6.1.5]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.CompositeFilter.doFilter(CompositeFilter.java:74) ~[spring-web-6.1.5.jar:6.1.5]
    at org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.WebMvcSecurityConfiguration$CompositeFilterChainProxy.doFilter(WebMvcSecurityConfiguration.java:230) ~[spring-security-config-6.2.3.jar:6.2.3]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:352) ~[spring-web-6.1.5.jar:6.1.5]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:268) ~[spring-web-6.1.5.jar:6.1.5]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:174) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.19.jar:10.1.19]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:149) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.19.jar:10.1.19]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.RequestContextFilter.doFilterInternal(RequestContextFilter.java:100) ~[spring-web-6.1.5.jar:6.1.5]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:116) ~[spring-web-6.1.5.jar:6.1.5]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:174) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.19.jar:10.1.19]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:149) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.19.jar:10.1.19]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.FormContentFilter.doFilterInternal(FormContentFilter.java:93) ~[spring-web-6.1.5.jar:6.1.5]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:116) ~[spring-web-6.1.5.jar:6.1.5]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:174) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.19.jar:10.1.19]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:149) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.19.jar:10.1.19]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.ServerHttpObservationFilter.doFilterInternal(ServerHttpObservationFilter.java:109) ~[spring-web-6.1.5.jar:6.1.5]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:116) ~[spring-web-6.1.5.jar:6.1.5]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:174) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.19.jar:10.1.19]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:149) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.19.jar:10.1.19]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:201) ~[spring-web-6.1.5.jar:6.1.5]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:116) ~[spring-web-6.1.5.jar:6.1.5]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:174) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.19.jar:10.1.19]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:149) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.19.jar:10.1.19]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:167) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.19.jar:10.1.19]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:90) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.19.jar:10.1.19]
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:482) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.19.jar:10.1.19]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:115) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.19.jar:10.1.19]
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:93) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.19.jar:10.1.19]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:74) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.19.jar:10.1.19]
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:344) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.19.jar:10.1.19]
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:391) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.19.jar:10.1.19]
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:63) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.19.jar:10.1.19]
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:896) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.19.jar:10.1.19]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1744) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.19.jar:10.1.19]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:52) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.19.jar:10.1.19]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1191) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.19.jar:10.1.19]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:659) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.19.jar:10.1.19]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:63) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.19.jar:10.1.19]
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:1583) ~[na:na]


Then I checked out a piece of source code org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ExceptionHandlerExceptionResolver:
...
    // Any other than the original exception (or a cause) is unintended here,
    // probably an accident (e.g. failed assertion or the like).
    if (!exceptions.contains(invocationEx) && logger.isWarnEnabled()) {
        logger.warn("Failure in @ExceptionHandler " + exceptionHandlerMethod, invocationEx);
    }
    // Continue with default processing of the original exception...
    return null;
...

I also use spring security, but I don't think it's relevant to this issue.
It is known that @ControllerAdvice can't handle error, but based on the logs it is known that this is a custom exception.
Can anyone explain why @ControllerAdvice is not working?

You are trying to handle multiple exceptions, yet your parameter is of type of the first exception (BadRequestException). I can only imagine that in case you get HttpMessageNotReadableException this will lead to an error.
To fix this the parameter should be of type Exception:
@ExceptionHandler(value = [BadRequestException::class, HttpMessageNotReadableException::class])
fun badRequestExceptionHandler(e: Exception): ResponseEntity<Unit> {
    logger.error("badRequestExceptionHandler")
    return ResponseEntity.badRequest().build()
}


It seems to be the result of this mistake.
